# MiniDumpWriteDump fails with "MiniDumpWithFullMemory"

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

I'm trying to get the process dump. But when I use flag `MiniDumpWithFullMemory` the function crashes.
Maybe I use `DuplicateHandle` wrong... I don't know.

Is `MiniDumpWithFullMemory` is necessary flag to obtain general information or I can use only other flags (like in code listing below) ??
I need to get the dump in order to send it to VirusTotal...

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;
#pragma comment(lib, "dbghelp.lib")
#include <dbghelp.h>
#include <stdio.h>


void WriteFullDump(wchar_t* path_to_dump, HANDLE hProc)
{
    const DWORD Flags = MiniDumpWithHandleData| 
        MiniDumpWithHandleData|
        MiniDumpWithDataSegs|
        MiniDumpScanMemory |
        MiniDumpFilterMemory|
        MiniDumpNormal|
        MiniDumpWithUnloadedModules|
        MiniDumpWithThreadInfo;

    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(path_to_dump, GENERIC_WRITE, 0, nullptr,CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, nullptr);
    BOOL Result = MiniDumpWriteDump(hProc,
            GetProcessId(hProc),
            hFile,
            (MINIDUMP_TYPE)Flags,
            nullptr,
            nullptr,
            nullptr);

        CloseHandle(hFile);

        if (!Result)
        {
            cout << Result << endl;
            std::cerr << "Looks like an error: MiniDumpWriteDump failed" << endl;
            cout << GetLastError() << endl;
        }
        CloseHandle(hFile);
    return;
}

int main()
{
    wchar_t* path = L"C:\\C++\\122332.txt";
    int pid;
    cin >> pid;
    HANDLE proc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE, 1, pid);
    HANDLE pseudoproc;
    HANDLE my = GetCurrentProcess();
    DuplicateHandle(proc, proc, my, &pseudoproc, PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, 1, DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS);

    WriteFullDump(path,proc);
    CloseHandle(proc);
    cout << "Finished!" << endl;
    char g;
    cin >> g;
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: So many things that could go wrong.  Add some (a lot) of error testing.  The error you are seeing is probably a run-on-error after a WIN32API call failed and the code continued.

Comment: If you decide to call `GetLastError`, make sure you call it at the right time. You are calling it way too late, at a time when its return value is indeterminate. Besides that, you appear to be using flags that require callbacks, but are passing `nullptr` for the *CallbackParam*. That doesn't look good.